# How do i get a folder icon on all the parent nodes and folder plus icon on all the child nodes(icon shoulbe on left side)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui, treeview

I want to get icons before the nodes of the Parent node and the child nodes. For parent nodes it should be icomoon-icon-folder-plus and for child nodes it should be 'icomoon-icon-folder'.

```
function treeView() {
  var treeMenu = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    template: kendo.template($("#treeview-template").html()),
    schema: {
      model: {
        id: "id",
        expanded: false,
        hasChildren: "HasChildren"
      }
    },
    transport: {
      read: {
        url: "/getTreeDetails",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
      },
    }
  });
  $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: treeMenu,
    dataValueField: "id",
    dataTextField: ['LABEL'],
    template: kendo.template($("#treeview-template").html())
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  treeView();
});
```

Script: icon is comming for all nodes on the right hand side.

```
<script id="treeview-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
        <span id='treeLabel' style='font-weight:bold;' data-id='#=item.id #'></span>
        #: item.LABEL #
       # if (item.hasChildren) { #
     <a href='\#'><span class='icomoon-icon-folder-plus'></span></a>
# } #
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
    <ul class="k-group k-treeview-lines" role="tree">
   <li class="k-item k-first" aria-selected="false " data-uid="3-72f2c45e0d7d" role="treeitem" aria-expanded="false" id="treeview_tv_active">
     <div class="k-top">
       <span class="k-icon k-plus" role="presentation"></span>
       <span class="k-in">
          <span id="treeLabel" data-id="64" style="font-weight:bold;">Team</span>
               </span>
          </div></li>
   <li class="k-item" aria-selected="false " data-uid="41d2-9e3c-69b6c8938c1d" role="treeitem"></li>
    <li class="k-item" aria-selected="false " data-uid="4546-b88b-f38f4b2e32e4" role="treeitem"></li>
    <li class="k-item" aria-selected="false " data-uid="44fa-8784-9c40a7b8ecf7" role="treeitem"></li>
    <li class="k-item k-last" aria-selected="false " data-uid="413f-b429-581cf6b58ee7" role="treeitem"></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: First, you should really fix up your code. You've got an extra `}` and [it should be better formatted.](http://jsbeautifier.org/)

Comment: Fixed the code and formatted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what do you want to achieve, but from the question i grasp that you wanted to

1. "get icons before the nodes" Does it mean place/put icon before the node ? i assumed yes cmiiw
2. and for parent node which have hasChildren attribute you want to put icomoon-icon-folder-plus, on the child node to put icomoon-icon-folder

So here i go

1. If you wanted to put it before the node instead of using template, i need to use the databound function.
2. From databound function you look through all `<li></li>` then loop through all of them and create conditional `if(hasChildren){ logic } else { logic}`

I haven't been able to use the template for such a purpose so this is the best way i could achieve it. and here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/machun/1847Ljkz/4/)

Comment: Thanks for your response but the desired output should be something like this <http://dojo.telerik.com/UFite/2> but according to your coe the icons are comming before the arrow and they are repeating when i click on arrow for example for child its comming two times and for 3rd child its comming 3 times

Comment: I modified you code 'before' to 'after' to get the images after the arrow button , but still the images are reapeating and getting same image to all the parent and child. And in your example what i figured out is there is no arrow for the child if it has no children but in my case i am getting arrows even if has no children. i guess that is causing issue but not getting how to resolve.

Comment: your link to the dojo is not working, and i dont see in my code in jsfiddle the repeating text

Comment: yes but its repeating for me if i use the same code

Comment: and even your code also worked but somehow i preferred template rathe than data-bind

Comment: i was using that workaround because i think that you wanted to add it **before the node**, because by using template we are only able to add it after the node

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the `list-style-image` CSS property.

```
ul {
  list-style-image: url('sqpurple.gif');
}
```

See examples and more information here - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-image.asp

Answer (score 0):

Created a template instead a datasource.

```
 # if (item.type= "true") { #
```

## }